# Possible to have too many storage shelves on walls? (re: weight limit?)

Tags: walls, shelving

I've been putting shelves on the unfinished side of the basement but they are really heavy. I've used a mix of 5/8" and 3/4" shelves:

[image: Shelves]

I'd like to install more shelving to the right of the existing shelves but is this too much?

Comment: As an exercise, consider what the walls hold up: the house. How heavy is your house? How heavy are these shelves?

Comment: Amount of shelves do not need to worry about, floor to ceiling on all four walls, is not too much.  The amount weight on the shelves and how you attach them to the walls is different.  Too much weight and the shelves might break or pull from the walls if not anchored enough(too small of screws,not enough screws), but the walls will still stay in place.

Comment: This looks to me like an electronics work area. In terms of hoarding status it's still amature hour, I've seen places that are loaded with 4x as much stuff in a smaller space.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not too much as long as you mount the racks or brackets into the walls with good concrete anchors or into the studs, which you must be doing because those heavy shelves haven't fallen down yet.

Comment: Thanks!  They are screwed into studs.

Comment: @SofaKng  So you have studs on an unfinished wall in a basement?

Comment: @SofaKng Are those walls indeed reinforced concrete?